Undefined variable $action. Can't pass route to a variable in a component, Laravel
I have a component with a form inside it. I assigned a variable to the action attribute:
<form action="{{ $action }}" method="{{ $method }}".
When I call the component using:
<x-component action="#" method="POST">,
or
<x-component action="route ('my-route')" method="POST">,
or
<x-component action="{{route ('my-route')}}" method="POST">,
It gives me an error saying "Undefined variable $action", and the log highlights the form tag.
The routes for that view is a controller function that does this:
$data = MyModel::all(); 

return view('pages.admin.dashboard', ['data' => $datab]);

I don't know if that is relevant to the problem or not though.
What is the cause of this problem and how to solve it?

first change $datab with $data

You might want to actually make a View component instead of using what seems to be an anonymous component, it will give you a bit more flexibility.

If you already have a view component, please show the code for the component.

If you change return view('pages.admin.dashboard', ['data' => $datab]); to return view('pages.admin.dashboard', ['data' => $data]);, is your problem still persisting?

Could you post a larger part of the code? Hard to figure something out from this.
